# Magnitude of discontinuity of $\arctan(\frac{x}{y})$ at $y=0$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Would it be correct to say that the magnitude of discontinuity of this function is $\pi$, since the right- and the left-sided limits at zero are equal to $|\pi|$?

I've never dealt with the concept of magnitude of discontinuity before, so just wondering.

The definition of the magnitude of discontinuity appears to be $\lim_{\epsilon\to 0} [\arctan(\frac{x}{\epsilon})-\arctan(\frac{x}{-\epsilon})]$.

Comment: By magnitude of discontinuity, do you mean jump of discontinuity?

Comment: Yes. $\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+} [\arctan(\frac{x}{\epsilon})-\arctan(\frac{x}{-\epsilon})]$